# How can I write a function so that a value is added only if it's not found in the macro already?

Tags: gnu-make

I'd a like a fairly generic way of conditionally adding a variable to macro if it's not already present.

Here's my attempt with gnu Make version 4.1:

```
$ cat Makefile 
define add_obj_dir
ifneq ($(1), $(filter $(1), $(OBJ_DIRS)))
OBJ_DIRS += $(1)
endif
endef

$(eval $(call add_obj_dir, "cat"))
$(eval $(call add_obj_dir, "cat"))
$(eval $(call add_obj_dir, "cat"))

all:
    @echo $(OBJ_DIRS)
$ 
$ 
$ make
cat cat cat
$
```

The output I'd like to see is one "cat" (not multiple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `if` function, not `ifdef`.  *Way* simpler.

```
add_obj_dir = $(if $(filter $1,$(OBJ_DIRS)),,OBJ_DIRS += $1)

$(eval (call add_obj_dir,cat))
$(eval (call add_obj_dir,cat))
$(eval (call add_obj_dir,cat))

all: ; @echo $(OBJ_DIRS)
```